# VueJS select object from list and display with function

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, emit, vue-props

I need to get the element I click which is displayed in a list. And print this element on a method which is on my vue instance throug mail-list tag which is on index.html

So I have Vue component which iterates json object and only prints two attributes from every element of it:

```
Vue.component('mail-list', {
  props: ['inboxmail'],
  methods: {
    selectmail: function(){
      this.$emit('selectmail', this.mail);
    }

  },
  template:
  `
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="i in inboxmail" @click="selectedmail">
      {{i.from}}:{{i.subject}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  `
  });
```

After run this I have two elements displayed on my index.html which are:

- test1@test.com:Hi
- test2@test.com:How are you?

I want to click one of this two elements and get the one I clicked. Then send it to vue method called setSelectedMail throug mail-list tag which is in index.html

index.html:

```
<div id="app">
        <mail-list v-bind:inboxmail="inbox" @selectmail="setSelectedMail($event)"></mail-list>
</div>
```

And finally, heres is the vue instance from where I want to get the selected mail:

```
let options = {
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    inbox: '',
    selectedMail:{}
  },
  methods: {
      setSelectedMail: function(mail){
          this.selectedMail = mail;
      }

  } //end methods
 }
//ViewModel (vm)
let vm = new Vue(options);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `@click="selectedmail(id)"`?

Comment: @Deda you're right! Thank you! But I was missing to pass the value to the function too:                                           
 selectmail: function(value) {
          this.$emit("selectmail", value);
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this. some corrections in your code.

```
@click="selectmail(i.from)"

methods: {
        selectmail: function(value) {
          this.$emit("selectmail", value);
        }
      }
```

Demo with your code in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/httpsstackoverflowcomquestions62075271-wl4oc?file=/src/App.vue:0-930) or [Github](https://github.com/rafaelchagasb/answers-stackoverflow/tree/master/stackoverflow.com/vuejs/62075271/example).

```
<!-- Complete code -->

<!-- MailList -->

<template>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="i in inboxmail" @click="selectmail(i.from)" 
      v-bind:key="i.from">{{i.from}}:{{i.subject}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "MailList",
  props: ["inboxmail"],
  methods: {
    selectmail: function(value) {
      this.$emit("selectmail", value);
    }
  }
};
</script>

<!-- App.Vue -->

<template>
  <div id="app">
    <mail-list v-bind:inboxmail="inbox" 
      @selectmail="setSelectedMail($event)">
    </mail-list>

    Selected: {{selectedMail}}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from "./components/HelloWorld";
import MailList from "./components/MailList";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    HelloWorld, MailList
  },
  data: function(){
    return {
      inbox: [{
        from: 'test1@test.com',
        subject: 'Hi'
      },{
        from: 'test2@test.com',
        subject: 'How are you?'
      }],
      selectedMail: {}
    };
  },
  methods: {
    setSelectedMail: function(mail) {
      this.selectedMail = mail;
    }
  } //end methods
};
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: "Avenir", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you for your help!